'this' - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type
I have defined 3 @Viewchild  template refs and an array
  @ViewChild('one') one!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('two') two!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('three') three!: TemplateRef<any>;

  templatesList = ['one','two'];
  
  templateRefsList: Array<TemplateRef<any>> = [];

Now AfterViewInit, I want to push the templatesRef that match the elements in array
  for (let i = 0; i < templatesList.length, i++) {
    this.templateRefsList.push(this[templatesList[i]])
  }

But while accessing 'this', it gives following error.

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

How can I push the templateRef elements in list in loop?

templatesList has no explicit type and is inferred as string[]. But in order to access properties of your class via index, the variable needs to have type keyof YourComponent. So you need to specify the type of your array as the following:
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('one') one!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('two') two!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('three') three!: TemplateRef<any>;

  templatesList: (keyof YourComponent)[] = ['one','two'];
  
  templateRefsList: Array<TemplateRef<any>> = [];

  yourFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < templatesList.length, i++) {
      this.templateRefsList.push(this[templatesList[i]])
    }
  }
}


You should explicitely define the type by setting the known properties of the array. Since all the properties of the array are TemplateRef<any>, the type will be inferred as the same and the error will go away.
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('one') one!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('two') two!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('three') three!: TemplateRef<any>;

  templatesList: Array<'one' | 'two' | 'three'> = ['one', 'two'];

  templateRefsList: Array<TemplateRef<any>> = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.templatesList.length; i++) {
      this.templateRefsList.push(this[this.templatesList[i]]);
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

So, is it that every variable in this component should be explicitly defined?

@Charmi just the view childs, this is one possible solution

I don't have much time to explain things in very much detail.
But I've had a similar issue to yours before.
If you want to access properties as a strings you would want to cast your object, in this case your class as any. This way you can access your properties by using ["key"]
    for (let i = 0; i < this.templatesList.length; i++) {
      this.templateRefsList.push((this as any)[this.templatesList[i]])
    }

With this code it should loop over your templatesList and look for this["one"] and this["two"] which are the names of your properties.
If it does not work feel free to let me know and I'll try to take a more in-depth look.

as any just silences the error. The proper solution is to use the correct types.

It does silence the issue, however you cannot access types by using strings that way. At least from my experience with a similar issue.

In most cases like this one, you can use the keyof operator to get the right type
